# lua_open returns null using luaJIT

Tags: c++, lua, embedding, luajit, lua-api

Using the recent luaJIT `lua_open` returns `null`. This does not happen with the regular lua library.

```
lua_State *L = lua_open();
std::cout << L << std::endl;
```

Output: `0x0`

How can I get luaJIT to work?

SSCCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <luajit-2.0/lua.hpp>
//linked library: libluajit-5.1.a

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate(); // lua_open();
    std::cout << L << std::endl; // 0x0
}
```

Additional information: Built on OSX 10.9 from source (tried both 2.0.2 and from git) with `make` and `make install`. Using compiler:

```
$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

(Using the luajit command line application `luajit` works fine, a test script gets executed without errors.)

Comment: Which version of LuaJIT are you using?

Comment: @RyanStein Current stable version 2.0.2.

Comment: Wasn't lua_open replaced by lua_newstate? Unless you're using your own mem manager, you should be able to use luaL_newstate which is lua_newstate with default mem manager.

Comment: With luajit you need to use luaL_newstate instead of lua_newstate anyway but as RyanStein indicates in his comment below lua_open is a define for luaL_newstate.

Comment: Is what you've posted your entire test case for this problem?

Comment: @RyanStein Yes, I added an SSCCE that yields the result for me.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the result. Can you provide more information about your environment? OS, compiler, etc.

Comment: agree with @RyanStein. I cannot reproduce this problem on my Win7 mingw-gcc setup either. How do you have luajit setup on your system? Did you build it directly from luajit's git repo? Was it from a distro package manager? etc.

Comment: @greatwolf I added the details to the question.

Comment: The only time `luaL_newstate` would return `NULL` is due to a memory allocation error. Have you tried using [`lua_newstate`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_newstate) with a [custom allocator](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_Alloc) yet?

Comment: @Ryan LuaJIT doesn't support custom allocators when built for 64 bit processors, and probably won't support it in 32 bit processors when the new GC rolls out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Apparently, x64 Mac applications need special handling; see http://luajit.org/install.html.

> If you're building a 64 bit application on OSX which links directly or indirectly
> against LuaJIT, you need to link your main executable with these flags:
>
> ```
> -pagezero_size 10000 -image_base 100000000
> ```

Comment: Do you also know how these arguments affect the linking step?

Comment: I know that LuaJIT on x64 needs to allocate memory in the lower 2GB range. I think these flags set up the process to let LuaJIT be able to use that range, but I'm not sure what exactly they do (a search for 'pagezero_size' returns more LuaJIT-related results than what it actually does.)

Comment: In case that I have no control over my main executable (e.g. because I need to use a main exec binary which is provided by my system and I cannot change that), is there any work around or other way? Preferably a dynamic way? Can I somehow make LuaJIT still work? Or maybe automatically switch to the standard Lua in that case...