# Need help on creating a UDF, returning "Unable to create a new Lua state"

Tags: go, lua, aerospike, aerospike-ce

I need to ask a question on creating UDF on aerospike. My configuration is as below:

- M1 Macbook Pro
- Docker using latest aerospike

My application is running this code:

```
AerospikeClient.RegisterUDF(nil, []byte({UDF_BODY}), {UDF_FILENAME}+".lua", aerospike.LUA)
```

and it keeps on producing this error:

```
Error registering UDF in aerospike.     common_error="Registration failed: compile_error\nFile: \nLine: 0\nMessage: Unable to create a new Lua state"
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to resolve this error?

I searched the forum and I don't think there is anybody that have encountered the same issue as me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message itself comes from [`aerospike/aerospike-mod-lua/src/main/mod_lua.c#validate()`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-mod-lua/blob/57ee412f1089a9c2557b4e566b9dbf33fdbbfbbe/src/main/mod_lua.c#L1020-L1042), relayed by [`aerospike/aerospike-client-go/client.go#RegisterUDF()`](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/blob/b1764d5cdb4d1b3349e52c14dacfa330ba0d7c42/client.go#L676-L713)

Considering the filename is empty in the error message, it makes sense it triggers from the code, because `lua_open()` returns null, [which has been seen before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20858911/6309) as a linking option issue.
In that page, `lua_open()` is a macro for `luaL_newstate()`, and this error could reflect the fact the [M1 support for luajit](https://doesitarm.com/formula/luajit/) is not yet fully completed.

The [OP David Budiman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17496305/david-budiman) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70093217/need-help-on-creating-a-udf-returning-unable-to-create-a-new-lua-state/70120631?noredirect=1#comment124031300_70120631):

> My teammates that are not using M1 macbook do not encounter this problem.  I'll try to use another machine first

Comment: Okay, I tried your suggestion. I put the filename on the server path argument. But, the same error still pops up. Was the filename supposed to be on another argument?

Comment: @DavidBudiman Not sure: maybe this is due to the lack of full M1 support, as I mention in my answer?

Comment: Maybe, my teammate that are not using M1 macbook do not encounter this problem.  I'll try to use another machine first

Comment: it seems that the lack of M1 support for LuaJIT really is the cause of this issue. Because of that, I'll accept your answer since you do answer the problem

Comment: @DavidBudiman No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow.